# Best controls to use on a settings form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm just designing a settings form for my app, nothing too fancy, It's a small app. I'm just wondering what controls are good for this? at the moment I'm using labels and textboxes and listboxes, but It's just looking crap and awkward, Is there some orthodox way to do this? Is is more horrible attempt at UI design. 
[image: settings form]

Comment: For true/false options, a checkbox is typically the way those are done. One or more options, perhaps a radio button group.

Comment: Have a look a `PropertyGrid` control, very handy for settings.

Comment: You can also look at the [`PropertyGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.100).aspx) Class as in this [Example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/PropertyGridInCSharp11302005004139AM/PropertyGridInCSharp.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can produce some really intuitive, aesthetic interfaces with the most primative controls and a dash of creativity or inspiration. Here's a settings UI I created recently:

[image]

### General Tips

- A nice choice of font goes a long way. My personal favorite at the moment is `Segoe UI`.
- Position controls using the designer rulers so that they are all relative of one another. Be consistent with your positioning too; don't position a caption above a TextBox for one field and besides the TextBox for another.
- Try and find a nice size for your controls, small controls are hard to use and large controls look very amateur.
- I think that setting the Form's `Maximize` property to `false` and changing the `FormBorderStyle` property to `FixedSingle` works well with small, fixed forms.

It's a good idea to get inspired. Take a look at some other projects of a similar caliber to yours and see how they position their UI.

Comment: Rather than explicitly choosing a font like Segoe UI, use the `SystemFonts` class to get it to automatically choose an appropriate font. I don't like how Winforms apps are designed to use MS Sans Serif by default :(

Comment: That looks so awesome. 
Screw the property grid, panel and checkboxes ftw.

Answer (score 0):

For something quick-and-dirty, create a class that is a Model of your application's settings, like so:

```
public class ApplicationSettings {
    public String YourName { get; set; }
    public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
}
```

Then use that with a `PropertyGrid` control:

```
ApplicationSettings settings = new ApplicationSettings();
LoadSettingsFromDB( settings );
propertyGrid.SelectedObject = settings;
```

After the user hits OK, just persist. The property values of your `settings` instance will be updated.

You can also use the PropertyGrid with the VS IDE-generated AppSettings feature.